# Single APK multiple Android Market "products"

Tags: android, apk, google-play, product

I have an app which has two levels of functionality, which can be "packaged" as two products both paid.  The codeset is the same; the app simply works off this config of level and inhibits/enables features appropriately.

Can i upload one APK and mark some "option" or config so that it appears as two products on Android Market? Or am i "stuck" with creating two APKs, with the config level somehow hardcoded into the xml or code?

In either case, what has worked for you?

Thanks,
S-

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is a library and two applications with different package IDs that refer to it. All the functionality is in the library, activities and all. The decision which flavor of the application to expose is made based upon the package ID.

The Java package name of the app does not have to match the APK package name. All you have to do is to place a full class name into the manifest. If you don't have package name hard-coded anywhere else in the app (and why should you?), you'd be fine.